# Amazon DynamoDB Exception: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to establish a connection to Amazon DynamoDB through a Spring Boot component using '**aws-java-sdk-dynamodb**'.

I'm providing the Access Key and Secret Key, but I'm receiving an exception indicating an invalid security token, even though I'm not passing one.

Here's the exception I'm encountering:

```
   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 3JNS4E8K8PR6MG2VLLH6M152R3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.725.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.725.jar:na]
```

I'd like to clarify whether a security token is required to connect to AWS DynamoDB from a Spring Boot component in Java. I have gone through with so many sample codes but didn't find any with Security Token.
I'm following the code reference in the repository at:
https://github.com/yogsma/betterjavacode/tree/main/dynamodbdemo

Could you please provide references on how to establish a successful connection to DynamoDB from a Spring Boot Java component?

Comment: share your aws config codes.

Comment: Shared on the registered email address

Comment: If I remember correctly, the message "The security token included in the request is invalid." doesn't refer specifically to the "session token" (the third part of the authentication when using temporary sessions) but can also mean that your access key id or secret key are wrong.

Comment: @NadavHar'El, Access key id and Secret key are correct, I validated the same.
When I include all three: Accesskey, Secret, and Session in the code, I used 'BasicSessionCredentials,' instead of BasicAWSCredentials in Code and it works. However, when I tried with just Accesskey and Secret, I encountered the mentioned exception. My concern is that connecting to AWS DynamoDB requires a security token, and I couldn't find any sample code that includes a security token. I would like to know how to connect to DynamoDB using just the Accesskey and Secret without needing to pass a security token

Comment: You are using an SDK version that is considered not best practice.

Comment: @smac2020, can you please suggest the correct one ?

Comment: See response. A lot of information there.

Comment: @smac2020, Still getting the similar Issue:

The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: I843LDSR6O0K011KEI8O0BPQIFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try a fresh Java Maven project and pull in the POM file located here - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb.  I want to make sure you get a basic AWS DynanoDB project working. Also - put your creds under \.aws\credentials as discussed in the link in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of the Java SDK. You should strongly consider moving to [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). V1 is not best practice.

The Amazon DynamoDB V2 Java API lets you perform service operations using your keys. To do so, ensure you configure your keys properly. See [Credential settings retrieval order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html).

Here is an example that simply lists your tables. Try this code to make sure it works.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.list_tables.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.ListTablesRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.ListTablesResponse;
import java.util.List;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.list_tables.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class ListTables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Listing your Amazon DynamoDB tables:\n");
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
               .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .region(region)
                .build();
        listAllTables(ddb);
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.list_tables.main]
    public static void listAllTables(DynamoDbClient ddb){

        boolean moreTables = true;
        String lastName = null;

        while(moreTables) {
            try {
                ListTablesResponse response = null;
                if (lastName == null) {
                    ListTablesRequest request = ListTablesRequest.builder().build();
                    response = ddb.listTables(request);
                } else {
                    ListTablesRequest request = ListTablesRequest.builder()
                            .exclusiveStartTableName(lastName).build();
                    response = ddb.listTables(request);
                }

                List<String> tableNames = response.tableNames();
                if (tableNames.size() > 0) {
                    for (String curName : tableNames) {
                        System.out.format("* %s\n", curName);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No tables found!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                lastName = response.lastEvaluatedTableName();
                if (lastName == null) {
                    moreTables = false;
                }

            } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nDone!");
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.list_tables.main]
}
```

After you get that working, you can try more advanced examples such as:

*Discusses how to develop a Spring Boot application that queries Amazon DynamoDB data. The Spring Boot application uses the AWS SDK for Java (v2) to invoke AWS services and is used by a React application that displays the data. The React application uses Cloudscape.*

See - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app